# How can i translate custom module text that i cant with inline translate in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, localisation, inline-translations

There are many text in my custom theme and modules that i can't translate.
I tried inline translate but there's no little book or red dots.
Also tried to create i18n folders inside and outside the modules' root folder with `en_US.csv` and `hu_HU.csv` after changing the locale but nothing.

This is what i see when i check the source code:

```
<th class=" purchased-date" scope:"col">Purchased Date</th>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are using translatable strings. For example:

```
<h3><?php echo __('Create Backup') ?></h3>
```

You can translate the strings with inline translation or i18n theme packages if you've done everything correctly.

Source: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_theory.html

Comment: This is the current source code:
<th class=" purchased-date" scope:"col">Purchased Date</th>

Comment: You can read everything here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_theory.html

Comment: Thank i changed the code as you suggested and works now.